# How do you find instantaneous power?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, power

I was wondering is there a way to find instantaneous power when you are not given an equation relating work with time but only the numerical values of quantities like force, mass of body, acceleration and time at which you want to find the power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that in Newtonian physics, kinetic energy and momentum are related as $$E=\frac{p^2}{2m}$$ 
If no specific interaction is given, there is no potential energy hence the total energy is simply the kinetic energy. If an external agent is changing this energy, then the power of that external agent is $$P=\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{p}{m}\frac{dp}{dt}$$ If we now use Newton's second law $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ we get $$P=\frac{p}{m}F$$

In the question OP says the numeric value of force is given, hence I assume force is constant. That means we can integrate Newton's third law to get $$p=Ft$$ where I use the fact that the body was initially at rest, stated by OP in the comments, and where $t$ is the duration for which the force is applied. Therefore, the power $P$ is $$P=\frac{F^2}{m}t$$

Answer (score 1):

Well the power is given by $P=\vec{F}\cdot\vec{v}$, so this may be useful to you, if you have the velocity of your body at some instant in time as well.

Comment: But we can't find instantaneous with the data given in question.

Comment: @drake01 you need the velocity.  For example if you apply a force perpendicular to $\vec{v}$, it doesn't do any work at all, and so $P=0$ in that case.  Without knowing $\vec{v}$, we wouldn't know if we were in the case or not.

Comment: I have an equation which relates force with time, it is also provided that particle was initially at rest at origin, how do I approach this ?